# QT MQTT secure connection

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, mqtt

I have setup a local mosquitto server; I can connect to it using QT (5.15.0) MQTT without SSL.

Trying to configure it with SSL, saw different posts on the subject. I still am unable to TLS handshake correctly with the server.

I am able to connect to the mosquitto server, but it states socket error and disconnects:

```
1598878059: mosquitto version 1.6.10 starting
1598878059: Config loaded from .\mosquitto.conf.
1598878059: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8883.
1598878059: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
1598878082: New connection from 192.168.1.34 on port 8883.
1598878082: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
```

It needs to be noted that, MQTT.fx client can talk to the same local mosquitto installation/configuration successfully using SSL/TLS and the same certificate. The Qt MQTT code alone is having the Socket error issue.

The mosquitto config is quite simple:

```
# Port to use for the default listener.
port 8883


# At least one of cafile or capath must be defined. They both
# define methods of accessing the PEM encoded Certificate
# Authority certificates that have signed your server certificate
# and that you wish to trust.
# cafile defines the path to a file containing the CA certificates.
# capath defines a directory that will be searched for files
# containing the CA certificates. For capath to work correctly, the
# certificate files must have ".crt" as the file ending and you must run
# "openssl rehash <path to capath>" each time you add/remove a certificate.
#cafile
#capath

cafile C:\Program Files\mosquitto\certs\m2mqtt_ca.crt

# Path to the PEM encoded server certificate.
certfile C:\Program Files\mosquitto\certs\m2mqtt_srv.crt

# Path to the PEM encoded keyfile.
keyfile C:\Program Files\mosquitto\certs\m2mqtt_srv.key
```

On the client side, I do see this:

```
"OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019"
true
"OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019"
Default SSL configuration isNull:  false
SSL configuration used by QNAM isNull:  true
 State: Connecting
 State: Disconnected
256
```

The code that I have used to test the connection:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtMqtt>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkRequest>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkReply>
#include <QSslSocket>
#include <QSslConfiguration>
#if 1
const QByteArray pem = R"(-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
)";
#endif

// Connecting to Secure MQTT with QtMqtt and SSL
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57829480/how-do-i-perform-a-secure-mqtt-using-qtmqtt-and-ssl

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

//  const QString hostname{"test.mosquitto.org"};       // Mosquitto public test server
    const QString hostname{"192.168.1.34"};         // Local Mosquitto test server
    const quint16 port = 8883;
    const QMqttTopicName topic{"qtmqtt/ssl_test"};
    const QMqttTopicFilter filter{"qtmqtt/#"};
    QSslCertificate cert = QSslCertificate(pem, QSsl::Pem);

    QSslConfiguration config;               // Since QT 5.14, SSL transport config
    config.defaultConfiguration();
    config.setProtocol(QSsl::TlsV1_2);          // needs to be handled explicitly with
    config.addCaCertificate(cert);              // client.connectToHostEncrypted(config);
    config.setLocalCertificate(cert);

    QMqttClient client;
    client.setHostname(hostname);
    client.setPort(port);

    QNetworkAccessManager qnam;
    QNetworkRequest request;
    QNetworkReply *reply = qnam.get(request);

    // Check OpenSSL support is functional
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58625924/qt-error-message-qt-network-ssl-qsslsocketconnecttohostencrypted-tls-initia
    qDebug() << QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString();
    qDebug() << QSslSocket::supportsSsl();
    qDebug() << QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionString();

    // Check SSL configuration
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683826/qnetworkrequest-and-default-ssl-configuration
    qDebug() << "Default SSL configuration isNull: "
         << QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration().isNull();

    qDebug() << "SSL configuration used by QNAM isNull: "
         << reply->sslConfiguration().isNull();

    QObject::connect(&client, &QMqttClient::stateChanged, [](QMqttClient::ClientState state){
        if(state == QMqttClient::Disconnected)
        qDebug() << " State: Disconnected";
        else if(state == QMqttClient::Connecting)
        qDebug() << " State: Connecting";
        else if(state == QMqttClient::Connected)
        qDebug() << " State: Connected";
    });

    QObject::connect(&client, &QMqttClient::errorChanged, [](QMqttClient::ClientError error){
        qDebug() << error;

    });

    QObject::connect(&client, &QMqttClient::messageReceived, [](const QByteArray &message, const QMqttTopicName &topic){
        qDebug() << " Received Topic:" << topic.name() << " Message: " << message;
    });

    QTimer timer;
    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&client, &topic](){
        if(client.publish(topic,  QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString().toUtf8()) == -1)
        qDebug() << "Error: Could not publish message";
    });

    QObject::connect(&client, &QMqttClient::connected, [&client, &timer, &filter](){
        QMqttSubscription *subscription = client.subscribe(filter);
        if(!subscription)
        qDebug() << "Could not subscribe";
        timer.start(1000);
    });

    client.connectToHostEncrypted(config);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Edit the question to include your mosquitto config as well

Comment: Done! Added mosquitto config. Also, mosquitto config and certificate have been tested with MQTT.fx. It can publish and receive messages, successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this issue myself, and I did various settings on the `QMqttClient & QSslConfiguration`

so in order for the QtMqttClient to be able to connect to a secured mqtt broker on `8883` the CA certificate needs to be installed on the host

here are some steps I recommend doing to test your program/setup:

1. you need to do is to enroll your CA certificate on the host
2. copy your Ca certificate to: `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` folder
3. run the `sudo update-ca-certificates` command
4. configure your QMqttClient & QSslConfiguration

```cpp
QMqttClient m_mqttClient;

m_mqttClient.setHostname("127.0.0.1");
m_mqttClient.setPort(8883);
m_mqttClient.setUsername("x");
m_mqttClient.setPassword("y");
m_mqttClient.setClientId("woot-1");
// this is optional
m_mqttClient.setProtocolVersion(QMqttClient::ProtocolVersion::MQTT_5_0);

QSslConfiguration sslConfig = QSslConfiguration();

// depending on your configuration you might not need this
// but if you connect to your broker via its ip address and not its domain name you will need this
// another aspect of this setting has to do with the ip address that is embedded in the certificate
// if you don't have the ip address in the certificate of the ip address is a missmatch you will need this setting to overcome the ssl handshake stages
// so ... depending on how your infrastructure/broker is configured I recommend experimenting with this settings to actually see if you need it or not, in any case, make sure you know that this `QSslSocket::PeerVerifyMode::VerifyNone` means before using it
sslConfig.setPeerVerifyMode(QSslSocket::PeerVerifyMode::VerifyNone);

// these connect slots are for printing debug messages to check if everything is working as expected 
connect(&m_mqttClient, &QMqttClient::connected, [](){
  qDebug() << "connected";
});

connect(&m_mqttClient, &QMqttClient::errorChanged, [] (QMqttClient::ClientError error) {
      qDebug() << "errorChanged: " << (QMqttClient::ClientError) error;
});

connect(&m_mqttClient, &QMqttClient::disconnected, []() {
  qDebug() << "disconnected";
});

// pass the ssl conf
m_mqttClient.connectToHostEncrypted(sslConfig);
```

after this you should(hopefully) see that your client managed to connect to your mqtt broker on ssl port `8883` that is configured with self signed certitifcates

You can read more about `QSslSocket::PeerVerifyMode::VerifyNone` -> [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsslsocket.html#PeerVerifyMode-enum)

as the mqtt broker I used mosquitto which I brought up online using its docker image

here is the `mosquitto.conf` file content I used to configure the broker

```
listener 8883
allow_anonymous true

cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.crt
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.key


tls_version tlsv1.2
```

I hope you and the rest of the readers manage to overcome the `QMqttClient::TransportInvalid` error encountered on the client